# Regex to clean csv from confusing characters

Tags: java, python, regex, csv

My problem is:

I'm using a csv that came out from some software, and the issue is that this software is not handling csv so well cause there are some strings in the csv that have quote in them and what is wrapping a  string is also quotes so then im having issues parsing it.

so this is normal csv:

```
"one","two","three"
```

and here is my case:

```
"one","tw"o","three"
```

So I'm having issues parsing strings like `"tw"o"`. This is basically a problem with the software that is outputting the file, and I can't edit that software.

So I thought I could create a regex that will take the unnecessary quotes or commas and make sure that each string is wrapped in quotes and delimited by comma, does someone know how can i achieve it?

im using tototoshi library for scala

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you do not use Python's `csv` package to process the `.csv` file?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem im using tototoshi for scala, but those libraries cant parse it since its not a right format...if it was "one","two","three" no problem, but its "one","tw"o","three" so the library cant parse it

Comment: Why always looking towards regular expressions? Even if you find something for this, I *assume* that might look pretty horribly. Heck: you need **other** people to even think it up. How easy will it then be for you to **maintain** that regex over time? Meaning: sometimes one should consider sitting down and writing his *own* parser and do things explicitly; instead of throwing up a monster regex.

Answer (score 1):

I tried Python csv module, and it was able to do that (sounds like a hack but the input file is wrong after all, and using regex would be a hack too):

```
import csv

z = '''"one","tw"o","three"'''

cr = csv.reader([z])
print(next(cr))
```

result:

```
['one', 'two"', 'three']
```

For some reason, the quote has been moved in the end of the string (a valid way to put a double quote in a field would be to double it).

To remove it you can do

```
print([x.replace('"',"") for x in next(cr)])
```

to get

```
['one', 'two', 'three']
```

note that csv will issue 4 fields with `"one","tw",o","three"` so if the quote is followed by a comma, nothing works, only human verification can fix this.

Answer (score 0):

One pretty simple regex solution that may work for you is this:

regex:   `(?<=\w)"(?=\w) //global flag`

replace:  `'' //blank string`

As long as we can view "bad" double quotes as those that are surrounded by alphanumerics, this will work.  It's just *a lookbehind for a alphanumeric, a double quote, and lookahead for a alphanumeric*. It would not match a double quote escaped with a backslash or another double quote, so `""` or `\"` would be okay.

[demo here](https://regex101.com/r/3W7KtZ/1)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you can't predict what kind of values with unescaped quotes you might get. There's no way to clean this up reliably with regex.

Maybe try [univocity-parsers](http://www.univocity.com/pages/parsers-tutorial) as it has a CSV parser that can handle this sort of input properly. Example:

```
    //first configure the parser
    CsvParserSettings settings = new CsvParserSettings();

    //override the default unescape quote handling. This seems more appropriate for your case.
    settings.setUnescapedQuoteHandling(UnescapedQuoteHandling.STOP_AT_CLOSING_QUOTE);

    //then create a parser and parse your input line:
    CsvParser parser = new CsvParser(settings);
    List<String[]> results = parser.parseAll(<your input here>);
```

Hope it helps.

Disclaimer: I'm the author of this library. It's open-source and free (Apache v2.0 license)